# Convergence in distribution of truncated Gaussian variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable that is distributed normally with mean $\mu=0$ and variance $\sigma=1$.

Suppose that $X_n$ is a random variable for any positive integer $n$ with  [truncated normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) with $\mu=0$, $\sigma=1$ and $a=-n$ and $b=n$.

I expect that the sequence $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ of bounded random variables  converges in distribution to the unbounded random variable $X$.

1. Is is true?
2. Do you know a reference with a proof of this convergence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show that the MGFs of $X_n$ converge point-wise to the MGF of $X$. [We know that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution) 
$$
M_{X_n}(t)=e^{\mu t + 1/2\sigma^2t^2}\left(\frac{\Phi(\beta_n-\sigma t)-\Phi(\alpha_n-\sigma t)}{\Phi(\beta_n)-\Phi(\alpha_n)}\right)
$$
where $\beta_n:=\frac{n-\mu}\sigma$, $\alpha_n:=\frac{-n-\mu}\sigma$ and $n\in\mathbb N$. So, by the continuity of the CDF $\Phi$, $$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}M_{X_n}(t)=M_{X}(t).$$

Answer (score 1):

It's true and you don't need anything fancy to show it. Apply [this common definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_distribution) and just work with the CDF in the link you gave.

Comment: agreed, this is more direct. +1